# How to get binary data of PDF with out generating

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, itext

I have my PDF code and existing PDF layout where I am adding the data and creating the new pdf file, but I am not able to create my new pdf file or not able to download.

I need to read the newly generate PDF file and need to written the binary data

Please review below code

```
 MemoryStream pdfms = new MemoryStream();
 PdfReader reader;
 reader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("20171010_BillTemplate.pdf"));
 PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, pdfms);
 AcroFields pdfBillingFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
 pdfBillingFields.SetField("CT_Mail_Block",MailBlock.ToUpper());// some data
 pdfBillingFields.SetField("Cash_Only", Cash_Only); 
 formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
 formFiller.Writer.CloseStream = false;
 reader = new PdfReader(pdfms); // giving error 
 formFiller.Close();
 pdfms.Dispose();
```

What I need is with or with out Creating newly created file I need to get the binary data of file and send in return.

I had implemented this code in webapi
Reader is giving error as

```
PDF header signature not found.
```

**Please say is this a right way to get the binary data from above code?**

Comment: "I am not able to create my new pdf file or not able to download" please edit your question to specify whether you get an error, and if so what that error is.

Comment: I just need to get the binary data from new PDF file(I mean without generating new pdf file I want to just get the binary data), How should I get that from above code

Comment: @IanKemp I have updated the code, can you suggest some thing from your end